# Reference combined cell above

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a sheet with a lots of columns ordered in a hierarchical way with the cells merged:

[image: Example table]

I'd like to name those columns (in example: row 5) like this:`MainGroupA-SubGroupA-SubSubGroupA`.

Simply referencing the columns above in the classic way won't work as the field above isn't available anymore. (In the example: the fields B1 to F1) (i.e. I can't enter `A1&A2&A3` / `R[-4]C&R[-3]C&R[-2]C` as this formula tries to read from the "hidden" cells).

Is there a way to do this without manual work or the need to un-merge the parent-cells? I might be able to do this with some external text editor or even VBA but would prefer an "Excel formula solution" as it would stay updated for new groups and columns.

*To Clarify: I'd like all columns in Line 5 to have the text like in A5*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want:

> MainGroupA-SubGroupA-SubSubGroupA

in A5 then this should work:

```
=A1&"-"&A2&"-"&A3
```

*Edit* Then try:

```
 =OFFSET(A1,0,1-MOD(COLUMN(),6))&"-"&OFFSET(A2,0,MOD(COLUMN(),2)-1)&"-"&A3
```

though this won't give the same text as in A5 across the complete row.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but I'm looking for a formula I can apply to the **entire** row 5. If I use `=A1&"-"&A2&"-"&A3` it will stop working in Cell B5 as it will "translate" to `=B1&"-"&B2&"-"&B3` (B1 and B2 will be empty and not "MainGroupA")

Answer (score 0):

The answer from pnuts is great and helped me solve some test cases. It was however a little difficult to adapt and produced empty strings for the last column, so I also wrote a VBA-Function to do exactly what I need.

Open the VBA Editor (ALT + F11) and enter the following code in a new module:

```
Public Function checkLeftIfEmpty(start As range) As String
    If start.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        checkLeftIfEmpty = "Only a single cell allowed as parameter"
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim currentRange As range
    Set currentRange = start
    Do While currentRange.Column >= 1
         If currentRange.Value <> "" Then
            checkLeftIfEmpty = currentRange.Value
            Exit Function
        Else
            Set currentRange = currentRange.Offset(0, -1)
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

You can now use the function `checkLeftIfEmpty` to find the first cell left-side from your parameter which contains text: (This will be the text of the merged cell itself, if applied to a "hidden by merge" cell)

[image: Using checkLeftIfEmpty]

And also in combination to concatenate a string:

[image: Using checkLeftIfEmpty to concatenate a string]